# Rainloop for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rainloop

I was wondering if is possible to add composer package [imscp/rainloop](https://github.com/i-MSCP/rainloop) to Laravel project by composer autoload or if is there other way to achieve this.

Comment: This package last updated on 12 May 2019 (Almost 2 years ago)

Comment: Do you think that there is another possible way to use Rainloop in Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying .htaccess to redirect specific route to subdirectory of the project.